# Is there a sequel after LOTR events?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, elves

At the end of the book series, hobbits and elves sail to the east of the middle earth to unknown places and only humans stay in the Middle Earth.
What happened next?
Where did elves settled down?
Were there any other adventures?
Will there be a sequel to LOTR series?

Comment: @Shevliaskovic I mean a movie sequel or maybe someone's else sequel

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Hobbits and elves sail to Valinor, not unknown places.  What happened after might be in one of the History of Middle Earth books, but I have never read them.

Comment: *Lord of the Rings 2: The Revengening*

Comment: Not all hobbits sail to Valinor; only Bilbo and Frodo do that. The rest of the hobbits stay in the Shire, which Aragorn declares off-limits to humans, or in Bree (where they've interacted with humans for centuries anyway).

Comment: In a way history, since it was set in the real world as an alternative folklore. Though strictly that makes it a prequel to history, rather than history a sequel.

Comment: "A movie sequel or maybe someone's else sequel"? I don't think such a question is on-topic here, fan-fic makes for long and uncanonicalisable lists. However, there is one work set in Middle-Earth after the end of the Ring War which I find quite noteworthy indeed: [The Last Ringbearer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Ringbearer) by Kirill Eskov.

Comment: Non-english (Russian) dilogy by Perumov (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perumov) is somewhat epic and rather dark sequel. There's even attempt at English translation: http://rod.avantguardsystems.com

Comment: @MattGutting Nitpicking, but in the Fourth Age Samwise also sails West after his wife dies.

Comment: Perhaps. "Among [the Fairbairns, descendants of Elanor Gamgee] the tradition is handed down that Samwise ... passed over Sea, last of the Ringbearers." So it is strongly pointed to, but not strictly speaking confirmed.

Answer (score 17):

Tolkien begun, but didn't complete, a sequel called *the New Shadow* which eventually saw publication in *History of Middle-earth 12*.

In his own words (Letter 256):

> I did begin a story placed about 100 years after the Downfall [of Mordor], but it proved both sinister and depressing. Since we are dealing with Men it is inevitable that we should be concerned with the most regrettable feature of their nature: their quick satiety with good. So that the people of Gondor in times of peace, justice and prosperity, would become discontented and restless – while the dynasts descended from Aragorn would become just kings and governors – like Denethor or worse. I found that even so early there was an outcrop of revolutionary plots, about a centre of secret Satanistic religion; while Gondorian boys were playing at being Orcs and going round doing damage. I could have written a 'thriller' about the plot and its discovery and overthrow – but it would be just that. Not worth doing.

Comment: I did read that, as far as it goes. He seems to have decided that it couldn't be an epic, only a suspense novel, and he wasn't interested in that.

Comment: @MattGutting - So .... CSI: Gondor?

Comment: So he didn't really have a good enough imagination to make a sequel... bummer.

Comment: @TylerH Au contraire, he had so much imagination that he saw what would happen, and that none of that would be worth writing about.

Comment: @MarnixKlooster If you can only picture a story going one way, you don't have enough imagination, not "too much". Please don't be ridiculous.

Comment: @TylerH - given that the whole point of the end of LotR was the ending of the mythical ages and of the personification of evil in the form of a Dark Lord, it's difficult to see how the story could have gone any other way.  He'd already told his story and there was nothing more to say.

Answer (score 3):

Not as a sequence *per se*, but as an apocalypse of sorts; the [Dagor Dagorath](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Dagor_Dagorath) or Last Battle and Day of Doom.

Quoting the Second Profecy of Mandos:

> [...] When the world is old and the Powers grow weary, then Morgoth,
>   seeing that the guard sleepeth, shall come back through the Door of
>   the Night out of the Timeless Void; and he shall destroy the Sun and
>   the Moon.

(Truly) epic battle ensues.

Comment: That comes from an earlier work though doesn't it?

Comment: Tolkien wrote a lot of stuff set in Middle-Earth, it's not always clear what he held as canon, and was still polishing, and what ideas he had rejected.  The "Faring Forth" is another idea he wrote about...that the Elves would come back in the future and try to retake Middle-Earth, but would ultimately fail.

Comment: @Monty129 Actually that's a quote from the Silmarillion, finished around the same time as the LoTR series.

Comment: Remember, the Silmarillion was never intended for publication as such -- it was Tolkien's working notes on his world, cleaned up a bit by his son for those of use who were interested in his working method and a bit more of the backstory. It's a historical/legendary reference, not a single story or even a set of short stories. Worth reading if you're the kind of person who re-reads all the appendices of LOTR every time you re-read the book even though you've read it 30 times before (which I am), but I wouldn't recommend it for most folks.

Answer (score 0):

"Will there be a sequel" -- not officially unless someone convinces the Tolkien estate that they can produce something which is completely true to JRRT's ideas and ideals and language. Odds of that happening are close to nil.

I'm sure there's lots of fan-fiction out there. Not canon, of course.

I don't know if anyone has established whether any of Tolkien's short stories occur in the same world, and if so at what time relative to the end of the Third Age.